# Translation property in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ space

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $g(x)$ be a bounded measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}$, 
and $f(x)$ be in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Notation: $\int_\mathbb{R} h(x)dx=\ $the integration of measurable function $h$ over $\mathbb{R}$

I would like to ask if the following statements holds.

1. $\forall c\in\mathbb{R}\ \int_\mathbb{R}f(x+c)dx=\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)dx$
2. $\lim_{t\rightarrow0} \int_\mathbb{R} g(x)|f(x+t)-f(x)|dx=0$

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is this for any function $g$?

Comment: You can divide by t inside integral and multiply with it outside and see it as absolute value of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.

Comment: Thank G. Sassatelli for editing my work. To mathreadler, g(x) is a bounded measurable function, while to see it as a derivative, I have to take limit inside integrand, but I can't figure out why passing the limit inside is possible.

Comment: To mathreadler, moreover, we do not know if f' exists a.e.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch: Certainly $1.$ holds, because Lebesgue measure is translation invariant. For 2., try to prove it first for compactly supported continuous functions. This follows nicely from uniform continuity. To finish, use the fact that such functions are dense in $L^1.$